# Are Google Protocol Buffer messages validated?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Below is a .proto file from the [Google developer guide web page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview). Suppose the protocol buffer compiler is run on the .proto file to generate data access classes. Do those classes validate messages that are received? For example, does it validate that the "type" field has a value of MOBILE, HOME, or WORK, and nothing else? Suppose a message contains data not specified in the .proto file, do the classes alert the using application of this?

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data you receive is deserialized into the objects you have and any unknown field is ignored. I don't think there are any warnings when your application receives a field that doesn't exist in the protos it uses, but that should be easy to test.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#how-do-they-work):

> You can add new fields to your message formats without breaking
>   backwards-compatibility; old binaries simply ignore the new field when
>   parsing. So if you have a communications protocol that uses protocol
>   buffers as its data format, you can extend your protocol without
>   having to worry about breaking existing code.